# Extracting embedded Query in crystal reports in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Is there a way or a DLL using which we an extract an embedded query from crystal reports.
I was able to do the same using CRAXDRT in windows based application, but when i try to do the same thing in ASP.net, entire application hangs.

Answer (score 0):

The CRAXDRT Report.SQLQueryString property does NOT seem to have an equivalent property in the .Net SDK, and believe me, I've been looking.

It is, however, available in the RAS SDK.